# How to get Application Name and Version in a Portable Class Library?

Tags: uwp, portability

I was wondering how to get Product Name or Product Version in a Portable Class Library. So far I have tried all these below:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

The error here is GetExecutingAssembly() not found.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainManager.EntryAssembly.GetName().Version
```

The error here is AppDomain not found.

```
public static string Version
{
    get
    {
        var assembly = typeof(MyType).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        // In some PCL profiles the above line is: var assembly = typeof(MyType).Assembly;
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(assembly.FullName);
        return assemblyName.Version.Major + "." + assemblyName.Version.Minor;
    }
}
```

The problem with this one is this gives the version of the PCL, and not the app's version.

Thanks all.

Comment: Do you have access to that portable class library?

Comment: I think using dependency injection is the way to do this.

Comment: @GeraldGonzales yes I do have access to this PCL I am building: https://github.com/McoreD/TreeGUI/blob/master/treegui4/HelpersLib/AppInfo.cs

Answer (score 2):

Everything you have written is true. As far as I know, there is no common way across all supported platforms to get a reference to the entry assembly of the application, and there is no common API available for that in the portable class libraries.

However, this doesn't necessarily stop you from getting ahold of this information inside a portable class library. You will need to abstract away this functionality and take advantage of dependency injection to provide the correct implementation for each platform.

Your portable class library would implement a common interface:

```
public interface IProductInfoProvider
{
    string GetVersion();
}
```

For the full .NET framework you would implement it like this:

```
public class ProductInfoProvider : IProductInfoProvider
{
    public Version GetVersion()
    {
        return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    }
}
```

The class that needs the version information would accept an instance of `IProductInfoProvider` as a constructor parameter, allowing it to be called whenever necessary:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IProductInfoProvider _productInfoProvider;

    public MyClass(IProductInfoProvider productInfoProvider)
    {
        _productInfoProvider = productInfoProvider;
    }
}
```

When instantiating the class you would pass it the correct implementation of the interface:

```
var myInstance = new MyClass(new ProductInfoProvider());
```

Since you might want to instantiate the class inside the portable class library, you would use a dependency injection framework, such as [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) to define the correct implementation in the platform specific application initialization:

```
public class ApplicationModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load() 
    {
        this.Bind<IProductInfoProvider>().To<ProductInfoProvider>();
    }
}
```

This will allow Ninject to create a new instance of `MyClass` with the correct implementation of `IProductInfoProvider` injected.